# Специализация шаблона, по условию

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Использую `#include <type_traits>` такой работы с шаблонами не знаю, но хотелось бы разобраться. Где нибудь есть хороший материал по введению в такое "управление" шаблонами?

Я бы хотел понять, как специализировать шаблоны для указателя на класс, для указателя на простые типы и.т.д.

В данном коде, ошибка: `error C2593: неоднозначный "operator &"`
Он не может выбрать между операторами которые пометил ### в комментарии.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
// для массивов
// Для массивов указано правильно или можно сделать лучше?
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void operator&(T (& obj)[N][M]){}
// ###
template <typename T, size_t N>
void operator&(T (& obj)[N]){}

// для классов
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value,void>::type
operator&(T & obj){obj.serialize(*this,0);}

// для указателя на класс
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value,void>::type
operator&(T * obj){ if(obj != 0){obj->serialize(*this,0);}}

// ### для указателя на простые типы 
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<T>::value && !std::is_array<T>::value && !std::is_enum<T>::value,void>::type
operator&(T * obj){ if(obj != 0){}}

};

int main()
{
A a;

int * p_int;
a& p_int;

unsigned long long maps[200000];
a&maps;

std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему вы перегружаете унарный оператор, а в коде используете бинарный?

Comment: А как для operator& использовать унарный?

Answer (score 1):

**Позднее обновление**: ваша проверка не вполне правильна. Массив будет проходить вашу проверку на указатель, поскольку вы передаёте его в `operator&` как `T*` (а значит, он может сконвертироваться). Чтобы запретить конверсию, вы можете либо переписать функцию так:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_class<T>::value &&
    !std::is_array<T>::value &&
    !std::is_enum<T>::value, void>::type
operator&(T*& obj) { if (obj != 0) { /**/ } }
```

(это сработает, но только для lvalue-указателей), либо так:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_pointer<T>::value &&
    !std::is_class<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value &&
    !std::is_array<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value &&
    !std::is_enum<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value, void>::type
operator&(T obj) { if (obj != 0) { /**/ } }
```

---

**Старый ответ:**

Вы пошли неправильным путём: частичной специализации шаблонных функций **не существует**, то, что вы делаете — это [перегрузка](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)! Попробуйте лучше специализацию шаблонных классов.

У вас получаются две соперничающие перегрузки, понятно, что у вас неоднозначность.

Может быть, вам подойдёт такой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct A;

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A<T[N]>
{
    void operator & (T obj[N])
    {
        cout << "array" << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T*>
{
    void operator & (T* obj)
    {
        cout << "pointer" << endl;
    }
};

#define SERIALIZE(X) { A<decltype(X)> _a; _a & X; }

int main()
{
    unsigned long long maps[2000];
    SERIALIZE(maps);
    SERIALIZE(&maps[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт:

> array
>   pointer